# Webforms messed up 'Add content' button

Tags: webforms, dashboard

After I installed and enabled the [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module, my admin toolbar got messed up.

Whenever I click on 'Content -> Add Content' I immediately get redirected to `#overlay=node/add/webform`. I can still go to the separate content types by altering the link (eg. '#overlay=node/add/news').

I have tried disabling the module and uninstalling / reinstalling, but to no avail.

Is there a way to restore the functionality?

EDIT: Apparently my content types have disappeared...

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: Drupal versoion: 7 7.50
Module version: 7.x-4.14
If you want more info, you'll have to be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**:

Discovered that the items for basic page and article had both been marked as disabled (though not by me) in the navigation menu. Re-enabling them under admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation fixed the problem immediately.

[D7 Add Content is missing content types](https://www.drupal.org/node/1094238)